# How to perform JPEG compression in Python without writing/reading

Tags: python, image, jpeg, python-imaging-library

I'd like to work directly with compressed JPEG images. I know that with PIL/Pillow I can compress an image when I save it, and then read back the compressed image - e.g.

```
from PIL import Image
im1 = Image.open(IMAGE_FILE)
IMAGE_10 = os.path.join('./images/dog10.jpeg')
im1.save(IMAGE_10,"JPEG", quality=10)
im10 = Image.open(IMAGE_10)
```

but, I'd like a way to do this without the extraneous write and read. Is there some Python package with a function that will take an image and quality number as inputs and return a jpeg version of that image with the given quality?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/rigoneri/4716919

Comment: You can write to StringIO instead of a file.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For in-memory file-like stuff, you can use `StringIO`.
Take a look:

```
from io import StringIO # "import StringIO" directly in python2
from PIL import Image
im1 = Image.open(IMAGE_FILE)

# here, we create an empty string buffer    
buffer = StringIO.StringIO()
im1.save(buffer, "JPEG", quality=10)

# ... do something else ...

# write the buffer to a file to make sure it worked
with open("./photo-quality10.jpg", "w") as handle:
    handle.write(buffer.contents())
```

If you check the `photo-quality10.jpg` file, it should be the same image, but with 10% quality as the JPEG compression setting.

Comment: Doesn't work for me with Python 3.5. I changed `buffer = StringIO.String()` to `buffer = StringIO()` and imported `from io import StringIO`, but when I try to do `im1.save()` it crashes with `TypeError: string argument expected, got 'bytes'`

Comment: I think it's supposed to be: `buffer=StringIO.StringIO()`

Comment: Now you have to use BytesIO insted of StringIO
eg 
`from io import BytesIO` ;
`buffer = BytesIO()`

Comment: @Andrea993 I followed your update but got this error: `handle.write(buffer.contents()) … AttributeError: '_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'contents'`

Comment: I had to change: `with open("./photo-quality10.jpg", "wb") as handle:
    handle.write(buffer.getbuffer())`

Answer (score 12):

Using BytesIO

```
try:
    from cStringIO import StringIO as BytesIO
except ImportError:
    from io import BytesIO

def generate(self, image, format='jpeg'):
    im = self.generate_image(image)
    out = BytesIO()
    im.save(out, format=format,quality=75)
    out.seek(0)
    return out
```

StringIO is missing in Python3.0, ref to : [StringIO in python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914472/stringio-in-python3)

Answer (score 1):

As of January 2024, you can achieve what you want like this (updated version of [@Sam Gammon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/235582/sam-gammon)'s answer, tested using Python 3.9):

```py
from io import BytesIO

from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("test.jpg")

buffer = BytesIO()
img.save(buffer, "JPEG", quality=10)

with open("./test_quality_10.jpg", "wb") as handle:
    handle.write(buffer.getbuffer())
```