# Python codes using numpy and matplotlib without outputting result

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, analytics

I just started learning doing financial analytics with python today. I ran into a block of code and it requires importing numpy and matplotlib to run the codes and generate a graph(not sure if it really can).

The codes are like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'serif'

K = 8000
S = np.linspace(7000,9000,100)
h = np.maximum(S-K, 0)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(S, h, lw=2.5)
plt.xlabel('index level $S-t$ at maturity')
plt.ylabel("inner value of European call option")
plt.grid(True)
```

I installed both numpy and matplotlib but after I tried running the codes nothing came out.

I really don't know what went wrong. This is my first time using numpy and matplotlib and I have not idea how to solve this problem.

Please help!

Comment: Or `plt.savefig('somename.jpg')`.

Comment: ... at the end of your code

Comment: plt.show() worked! plt.savefig('somename.jpg') didn't work though. It says "Format "jpg" is not supported." Anyway thank you!

Comment: That's correct. [jpg is not a supported format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827016/matplotlib-savefig-in-jpeg-format). Other formats like png or pdf work as expected.

Comment: Nice to know that! Thanks!